# Can not change Header color in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

While learning PyQt5 I try to change color of the header in QTableWidget (let's it be green). But it is not changed and I have additional green part on the right instead.

[image]

I want only test1, test2 and test3 cells to be green.

```
self.Table = QTableWidget(TableFrameWidget)
self.Table.setFixedSize(98, 100)  
m = QHeaderView(Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, self.Table)
m.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')
self.Table.setHorizontalHeader(m)
self.Table.setColumnCount(3)
self.Table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['test1', 'test2', 'test3'])
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use [proper selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) for both the class type *and* the related subcontrol. See the [reference documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qheaderview-widget) and [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview): `m.setStyleSheet('QHeaderView::section { background: green; }')`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I used setStyleSheet without selectors earlier and it worked for some other objects. But now I know that I should specify them. Thank you one more time!

Comment: Generic properties work for very basic widgets, and only to some extent and with some limitations. Most complex widgets (such as QHeaderView, which actually is a scrollable item view) require more accurate selectors, especially if they are made of multiple elements. In your case, the stylesheet "worked" in the sense that it actually set the correct background to the whole header, but sections are always drawn *above* it and in some QStyles (like the default one in Windows) they also have a different color role, so they practically "overwrite" it making that property ineffective for them.

Comment: @musicamante Now understand. Thank you!

Comment: Why not answer your own question?